# Voltage divider with diode

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, diodes, voltage-divider

I'm having trouble analysing this circuit and was hoping someone could help me. The circuit in question is below.

[image]

I want to find the voltage drop and current across each of the parts. So far I've found the thevenin equivalent:

[image]

I'm a little confused as to how to find the current. Would I simply use $$\frac{11.2V}{13.33k\Omega}?$$

Or does the diode subtract 0.6 or so volts from the total voltage to be $$\frac{10.6V}{13.33k\Omega}?$$

Comment: The second is correct

Comment: And the next step would be to *verify* this current will actually make the diode into a region where it has the forward voltage drop you have assumed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Follow the arrows below. The first transition is due to making a Thevenin equivalent out of \$V_1\$, \$R_1\$, and \$R_2\$. The second transition is just summing the remaining two resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqlofE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There will therefore be about \$600\:\textrm{mV}\$ subtracted away from the Thevenin voltage, leaving \$5\:\textrm{V}\$ across the total resistance of \$10\:\textrm{k}\Omega\$. About \$500\:\mu\textrm{A}\$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended or off-topic discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58089/discussion-on-answer-by-jonk-voltage-divider-with-diode).